# Scraping webpage with a table rendered using javascript utilizing Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[the source html of the page i am trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqWGm.png)

Iam trying to scrape a webtable that is rendered using certain javascripts using Selenium Webdriver

```
driver.get("http://xxxxx:xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx-
xxxxxx.grid.xxxxxx.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/comp/queue.table");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List<WebElement> k=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='queue.table']"));
System.out.println(k.size());
System.out.println(k.get(0).getText());
```

k.size() returns 1
and when i run get text it returns only some entries from the table

[Actual table and entries the total rows are 135](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cNhF.png)

after running i get as follows

```
              Queue Management
 Loading...

 Name
 Type
 Status
 Enabled
 Group
 Total Entries
 Waiting Entries
 Severe/Failed Entries
 DeleteCompletedWorkItemsQueu e
 Process
 Started
 Enabled
 Default
 0
 0
 0
 DeliveryStatusOnStartup
 Process
 Started
 Enabled
 Default
 0
 0
 0
 DTODeliverablesQueue
 Process
 Started
 Enabled
 Default
 0
 0
 0
 DTOOffPeakQueue
 Process
 Started
 Enabled
 Default
 0
 0
 0
Loading.........
```

I get 25 entries of the table and rest is not present 
I am unable to understand why am i getting "Loading....."

Comment: may be you have to wait for the table to load all entries.

Comment: That just means that data is not there. Some sites only load data when you scrolldown. So either you need to scroll down and then do it or you need to use wait if the page is still loading

Comment: So is there any other means to read the entire table

Comment: is table is loading when scroll down or without scroll down?

Comment: I am trying to fetch the data using selenium so i am unaware as to how to scroll down programmatically

Comment: the table is like this code section with a separate scrollbar;i am not sure if it loads when i scroll down or not

Answer (score 1):

I think by using `List<WebElement> k=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='queue.table']"));` we are trying to make out a list with too many unwanted items in the list. Rather, I feel it would be effective to get hold of the nodes within `<td>` tags which contains the indented values and save into the list. Next we can iterate over the list and use either `getText()` method or `getAttribute()` method to retrieve the text as follows:

```
driver.get("http://xxxxx:xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx-xxxxxx.grid.xxxxxx.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/comp/queue.table");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List<WebElement> k = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='queue.table']//tr"));
System.out.println(k.size());
for (WebElement my_element:k)
    {
        String innerhtml = my_element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        System.out.println("Value from Table is : "+innerhtml); 
    }
```

Comment: I was looking for the text int the table rows and modifying to my_element.getText was also not that helpful as i get even less values in a repeated fashion

Comment: @josephfrancis As you can see, I have changed my code and now picking up the `<tr>` nodes and retrieving the text **not through `getText()`** but through **`getAttribute("innerHTML")`**. Please Accept the Answer if it caters to your Question.

Comment: Unfortunately no;appreciate your effort